# How do I explain a complicated function in Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a somewhat complicated R function (different parts refer to various equations I'd like to explain.)
I want to write my code using R Markdown, but I need to be able to explain the different parts of the function in the document. A bit like literate programming.

I wonder if it is possible to split the function definition across different code chunks, or maybe insert markdown comments inside the function definition?

I'd like the end result to look something like this:

```
complicated = function(x) {
```

I use *x^2* in the example so it is math, and yet short. Here it is in the actual R code:

```
  x^2
}
```

This doesn't work:

````
``` {r}
complicated = function(x) {
```
explain the function with some math $x^$.
``` {r}
 x^2
}
```
````

The following actually **does** work:

````
``` {r chunk1, echo=FALSE}
complicated=function(x) {
  x^2
}
```

``` {r chunk1, echo=1:2, eval=F}
```
In the complicated function I use x^2 as an example.
````

Though it is a bit tricky, because if lines in the function change, I have to edit everything again. Also in the Rmd file, you don't actually see the code described by the comments.

## Note:

Maybe it is possible to somehow have the relevant chunks written to a file without being evaluated, and then the file read in? I didn't manage to figure out a way yet...

Comment: ```{r, eval = T, echo = F} ``` should work, this will print the code in the chunk, but not run it.

Comment: Thank you. Do I have to then include the function a second time, where it is evaluated but not included in the output? I prefer to just have it once, but if that is not possible, I can include it once with comments and without evaluating, and once for running.

Comment: Why not have it evaluating and printing at the same time? I don't understand your use case.

Comment: I don't want to evaluate and print it at the same time, because I'd like to insert a formatted comment in the middle. (See my edited question above).
But I can evaluate and print a non-closed function.

Comment: You can't split up a function over multiple chunks. Define the function in one chunk, describe it line by line in subsequent chunks.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I now understand how that works. It still is a bit clunky, because I have to refer to line numbers from the function. I used literate programming before, and there I could comment on chunks that were parts of functions. Is it possible to refer to parts in ways other than line numbers (the echo=1:2 above)? In a way that would be more visible in the Rmd file?

Comment: How about splitting the function into multiple shorter ones that can each presented and explained without this code-prose inter-mixture?

Comment: The problem is that the function uses a large number of variables and temporary variables, and carrying these from one function to the next will be cumbersome.

I seems that R markdown is somewhat limited. For example, it would be hard to have functions and objects that belong inside other functions. Again, unless you write the whole thing as one chunk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a nice answer to this question, though it looks a bit like a knitr bug. I hope it doesn't get fixed. It turns out that references to chunks work in Rmd just like in Rnw. You just have to use `<<chunk name>>` to refer back to a chunk.

So, here is the answer:

````
```{r Xsquare, eval=F}
x^2
```
We just need to take x and raise it to the second power: $x^2$.

Now let us put it together:

```{r complicated, eval=T}
complicated = function(x) {
   <<Xsquare>>
}
```
````

Simple, right?

Turns out in Rstudio it works only when we knit everything together, but not on running a single chunk. Almost makes sense.

To solve this, in run the following: `knit("filename.Rmd")` in the console.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way, though I admit it's a little bit of a hack.

````
---
title: "Split Function"
output: html_document
---

```{r funcdef}
myfunc <- function(x) {
  x <- x + 1
  x <- x * 2
  return(x)
}
```

```{r funcdef1, echo = FALSE, eval = FALSE, include = FALSE}
x <- NULL
  x <- x + 1
  x <- x * 2
  return(x)
```

First line:

```{r funcdef1, echo=2, eval = FALSE}
```

Now the last two:

```{r funcdef1, echo=3:4, eval = FALSE}
```

Done!
````

[image: rmd, rendered into html]

Explanation:

- the first chunk `funcdef` is the full function definition, needed if we want to use it;
- the second chunk includes the first line (that I do not echo, omitted with `echo=-1`) that is there so that the others do not err with `'x' not found` (*even* if I do not eval or include); notice that it uses the same chunk name and has nothing in it
- same for the third chunk
- the reason I have to break out the body of the function without the `function` header and enclosing braces is that `echo=` using numbers allows us to subset which *expressions* are included, not which *lines* ... and a function declaration is one expression

Two things I don't really like about this:

1. It requires you to include the body of the function twice, so maintenance has more overhead than required;
2. It thinks `x` is being used, when all I really want is to reference the code.

Frankly, this may not be much better than including the portions of code within each subsequent chunk (and set `eval=FALSE`).