# Writing function in R markdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

Hi I have a very big function-i (to later use with a apply function) that I made in R studio. I am writing the function in R Markdown and I want to include text within the function-i to make it easier for the reader to understand what is happening within the function-i. Is there is a good way to do it?
I tried this way and it does not work:

````
```{r}
f <- function (i) {
 part 1
```{r}
Text or comment 1
```{r}
part 2
```{r}
Text or comment 2
```{r}
part 3
```{r}
Text or comment 3
```{r}
part4
}
````

It gives me several errors. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59082913/how-do-i-explain-a-complicated-function-in-rmarkdown?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I explain a complicated function in Rmarkdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59082913/how-do-i-explain-a-complicated-function-in-rmarkdown)